# Why goto 'label' repeats the statment before 'label:'?

Tags: c, loops, label, infinite-loop, goto

I want to create program that will compute factorial with goto statement instead of loop, and the problem is why goto 'factorial' repeats scanf before 'factorial:'?

The problem occur in this code:

```
int main(void) {

    int number;
    double n;

    scanf("%d", &number);
    n = number;

    factorial:
                if (number > 1) {
                    --number;
                    n *= number;
                }
                goto factorial;

    printf("n! = %f", n);

    return 0;
    }
```

When I put goto factorial within if statement everything is working fine:

```
int main(void) {

int number;
double n;

scanf("%d", &number);
n = number;

factorial:
            if (number > 1) {
                --number;
                n *= number;
                goto factorial;
            }

printf("n! = %f", n);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `factorial: if( ... ) { ... } goto factorial;` See the infinite loop? By the way, it is a bad idea to use `goto`s

Comment: So long as the jump is limited to a *near* jump within a function, the lowly `goto` is just fine. In fact it is the only tool you have for jumping out of nested loops. Beyond those limitations, you can run into trouble.

Comment: I doubt it repeats the `scanf` Instead it's an endless loop. Once `number` reach zero, it simply keeps executing the `if (number > 1)` followed by `goto factorial`

Comment: Why use `goto` at all when `while (number > 1)` does a better job?

Comment: Why do you expect that two clearly different programs do the same thing?

Answer (score 3):

This code snippet

```
factorial:
            if (number > 1) {
                --number;
                n *= number;
            }
            goto factorial;
```

produces an infinite loop. You can imagine it the following way

```
factorial:
            // some calculations
            goto factorial;
```

In this code snippet

```
factorial:
            if (number > 1) {
                --number;
                n *= number;
                goto factorial;
            }
```

the goto statement is executed only when number is greater than 1. So as soon as number becomes equal to 0 the control is passed outside the if statement and correspondingly bypasses the goto statement.